# Merging a game into WinRT app

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-runtime, xna

I'm wondering what options do I have to merge a 2D game into WinRT app that's already developed. I've developed couple of games in Unity3D but not sure if they can be played as a part of WinRT app (launch on button click).

I've heard Microsoft provide XNA framework for game development. Would that be of any help in my case? The requirement is to launch game on button click and get back to app on back button click.

Please let me know if there's better approach/tool available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was a 2D game that I wanted to integrate with my WinRT app, I decided to go with [Scirra Contstruct 2](https://www.scirra.com/construct2), designed specifically for 2D games. It exported the project as website which I hosted on my server and used a WebView within my app to load the game. Not only the performance is good, but, as a bi-product, it made the game cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you say you want to merge a game with a WinRT app - Do you mean you want to put a game inside another application, so perhaps have an app as a launch pad for you game? If you want to target WinRT with Unity I just looked at the platforms that Unity targets and Universal Windows Platform is listed there. You could write the application part in Unity couldn't you ? So that the app is just the first scene that you see. That might seem strange, but if you had to use unity and the app was just a small application with not too many requirements you could do it that way.

Xna has been discontinued. You should use other frameworks.

If you want to write it from scratch I would suggest that you write it as WinRT application (Universal Windows Platform) so that you can define the application UI in Xaml and write the game with a dedicated graphics/game api such as SharpDX http://sharpdx.org/ (which is a wrapper around DirectX) or perhaps even better, take a look at Win2D http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm which is a very impressive 2d graphics api.

In practice, both SharpDX and Win2D would target one of the Xaml controls that give you access to a swap-chain (eg SwapChainPanel, SwapChainBackgroundPanel, CanvasControl etc). These Xaml controls are integrated into the Xaml UI and can simply pop up when you need them and viola, your game is running.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. However, I happened to look at Construct 2. Created a demo and integrated into my WinRT app. Worked like a charm. But I'm not sure if Construct 2 will provide me with everything I need in my game. I'll have a look at both options you mentioned.